# raspberry gst-launch-1.0 how to make streaming video and simultaneously save on local file server

Tags: udp, video-streaming, raspberry-pi, raspbian, piping

it is just that I use gstreamer. how to make streaming video and simultaneously save on local file server. the client only needs to see.

I try with

```
gst-launch-1.0 rpicamsrc bitrate=1000000 !  h264parse ! rtph264pay pt=96 config-interval=5 ! udpsink host=192.168.1.53 port=5000 ! rtph264depay ! h264parse ! mp4mux ! filesink location=/root/Desktop/video_drone/prova.mp4
```

I tried with xxx, but I think it's wrong

Pretty much for the help, I am desperate I tried them all  :-(
tank's

Answer (score 1):

Your pipeline looks a bit weird and cobbled together.

You want to take a video source and pipe it both to network and to file. This means you want to split it up into two outputs. This requires the `tee` element.

```
gst-launch-1.0 rpicamsrc ! h264parse ! tee name=t \
  ! rtph264pay pt=96 ! udpsink host=192.168.1.53 port=5000 \
  t. ! mp4mux ! filesink location=/root/Desktop/video_drone/prova.mp4
```

One out goes "through" the `tee` and the other is started by the name `t.`